# List Filtering in Linq

Tags: c#, list, filtering

I have two lists. One is a list of Ids.
I've to filter the second list which is having the Ids in the former list only.
For that, I've written the below code

```
var Clientidlist = list.GroupBy(p => new {p.CompanyName, p.UserId})
                 .Select(s => s.Min(m => m.Id));

var olist = list.Where(x => Clientidlist.Contains(x.Id))
                 .OrderBy(x=>x.CompanyName).ToList();
```

But I think there something wrong in it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the issue? isn't it working

Comment: Your first query is a bit odd, what exactly are you trying to do?